# View Controller Trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am making a music streaming app but i can only seem to add the controls to the default view controller this is my code for ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;
}

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender;

@end
```

and this is my code for viewcontrol.m

```
-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender{

    NSString *stream = @"http://117.53.175.113:15008/listen.pls";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];

    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [WebView loadRequest:urlrequest];
}


@end
```

Please help

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing you have not mentioned anything?

Answer (score 0):

Drag you `IBOutlet` from interface builder and to outside class parentheses {}.

Something like:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView; // remove this.
}
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView * WebView;
```